# Excel VBA to change one value into 3 based on next column

Tags: excel, vba

First off I do not really know what I am doing so I am probably missing something obvious

I am currently using a macros to change a list of values.  I could probably use an index match function to do the same thing, but the macro just works better for our purposes.

I have not had any problems uptil now,  the formula replaces a with x and b with y; however I have a new variable that is really 3 variables in one.

this new variable needs to be replaced with one of three values based on what value that is contained in the column beside it.  This is what I use for the regular values:

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Range("C1").Activate
Selection.Replace What:="D", Replacement:="8D", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="E", Replacement:="8E", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

however I need to replace "-" with either "extra 1", "extra 2" or "extra 3" depending on whether Column D contains a 1,2, or 3 in the same row.  I know simply making an extra column with =c2&" "&d2 would solve my problems but, to make this process very easy for others I would like to keep it all to 1 key stroke.  Please feel free to disparage me if I deserve it.

[data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcR5n.jpg)

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't understand the scope of your question. I just can't seem to visualize what you're trying to achieve. Can you post a picture of the raw data, and then the ideal output of the code you're running?

Comment: Using an extra column (e.g. with a formula of `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"D","8D"),"E","8E"),"-","extra "&D1)`) would mean the users wouldn't even need the 1 keystroke that they currently use.

Comment: Here is what im working with for data:
|Name name|10/23/2016|[|1
|namey namerson|10/23/2016|{|1
|namerijsan| 10/23/2016|~|1
|namic|10/23/2016|+ |1


The issue surrounds is that this data has to be imported every day (and not always by me) and all the codes need to be changed.  +=12N     ~=extra staff 

the last column has the info with time of day (day,eve,night)  and i need to get that info combined with certain values (like ~ but not values like +)
I worked out how to do a similar thing with index(match()) but i want staff to be able to change the values and that deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably a very inefficient way to do things, but I just wrote some lines to create an extra column and do the concatenation there and then just copy it over the original data.